# Mysql return only pattern match from column

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have a column with a product description. I want to do a search on this column with a regexp and only return the match from the regexp instead of the complete content of the column.

i.e. I have a description

> This magnificent bead is high on detail

and

> The bracelet has a magnetic closure

```
SELECT description FROM products WHERE description RLIKE"'magn.*\s"
```

This should return **magnificent** and **magnetic**

```
SELECT description FROM products WHERE description RLIKE"'magni.*\s"
```

This should return **magnificent**

But of course this current queries return the complete descriptions. Any pointers how I could do this. MYSQL 5.5

Comment: Is that a typo "RLIKE"?

Comment: No, RLIKE is the same as REGEXP

Comment: Oh okay.. Excuse me.. Never seen that before :) @Jeroen Swets

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MySQL version 8.0, you can use regexp_substr() for this purpose. This function wasn't available in earlier versions.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr

### UPDATE

Here's another crack at it which should be 5.5 friendly. Assumes that the supplied regex is at the start of the required match.

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
  SUBSTRING(`description`, LOCATE('magni', `description`)), ' ', 1) 
FROM table1 
WHERE `description` REGEXP 'magni';
```

And a working version 8.0 example for whoever upvoted my previous effort

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('Those magnificent men in their flying machines', '[[:space:]]magni[^ ].*[[:space:]]');
```

Comment: Unfortunately the hoster is running 5.5

Comment: 3 versions behind = time for new hosting.

Comment: Probably, but that doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can use REGEXP in mySql to solve your problem like:

SELECT description FROM products WHERE description REGEXP 'magn.*'
    The above query will give u result magnificent and magnetic

SELECT description FROM products WHERE description REGEXP 'magni.*'
    The above query will give u result magnificent
```

Comment: This is the simplified version of my query. The matching of the pattern is not the problem, Its the returning value of the select which is the problem.